# Clickable dropdown menu should not close when clicking inside menu list

Tags: javascript, html, drop-down-menu

I'm making clickable dropdown menu so

1. when user clicks on green dropdown menu button, menu will open
2. and when user clicks again on green button, menu will close.
3. but when dropdown menu is open and user clicks outside of dropdown menu anywhere on page, menu will again close.

I have setup all this 3 steps and working fine but I want is, when dropdown menu is open, and user clicks inside menu area (red background color area) then menu should NOT CLOSE. I need ONLY JAVASCRIPT CODE FOR SAME. Even if you can do it with total new JAVASCRIPT code it will be helpful.

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover,
.dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1
}

.show {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
<p>when click here menu will close</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content" style="background:red;">
    <p>when click here menu should not close</p>
    <div id="test1">
      <p>when click here menu should not close</p>
    </div>
    <div id="test2">
      <div id="subtest1">
        <p>when click here menu should not close</p>
      </div>
      <div id="subtest1">
        <p>when click here menu should not close</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>when click here menu will close</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just add click event on your dropdown and stop the propagation to prevent event bubble up to window. So, when use click in the dropdown, the window object never catch click event.

```
// Prevent event bubble up to window.
document.getElementById("myDropdown").addEventListener('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});

// Inline event also working well, if you prefer this style.
<div id="myDropdown" onclick="event.stopPropagation()" class="dropdown-content" style="background:red;">
```

```js
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Prevent event bubble up to window.
document.getElementById("myDropdown").addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});

// Close the dropdown if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    min-width: 160px;
    overflow: auto;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.show {display:block;}
```

```html
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>
<p>when click here menu will close</p>
<div class="dropdown">
  <button onclick="myFunction()" class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div id="myDropdown" class="dropdown-content" style="background:red;">
    
    <p>when click here menu should not close</p>
    <div id="test1">
      <p>when click here menu should not close</p>
    </div>
    <div id="test2">
      <div id="subtest1">
        <p>when click here menu should not close</p>
      </div>
      <div id="subtest1">
        <p>when click here menu should not close</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<p>when click here menu will close</p>
```

Comment: so u mean to say all i need is to just add onclick="event.stopPropagation()" in div which i want to make non-clickable that's it ? no any other code modification u did i guess !

Comment: Yes, just add `onclick="event.stopPropagation()"` to `#myDropdown` and it should work, nothing more.. but I prefer you should separate your html and javascript code.

Comment: ohh thanks i will take care of that in future thanks

Answer (score 1):

That's the smallest JavaScript I could come up with... *;-)*

```css
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  outline: none;            /* add */
}

.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
  background-color: #3e8e41;
}

.dropdown .dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  top:100%;            /* add */
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
  
  transition: 0.3s;    /* add */
  visibility: hidden;  /* add */
  opacity:0;           /* add */
}

.dropdown:focus .dropdown-content { /* add all */
  outline: none;
  visibility: visible;
  opacity:1;
  transform: translateY(10px);
}
```

```html
<p>Click on the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown" tabindex="1"> <!-- set tabindex -->
  <a class="dropbtn">Dropdown</a> <!-- Don't use Button -->
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <p>when click here menu should not close</p>
    <div id="test1">
      <p>when click here menu should not close</p>
    </div>
    <div id="test2">
      <div id="subtest1">
        <p>when click here menu should not close</p>
      </div>
      <div id="subtest1">
        <p>when click here menu should not close</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Ups!.. there's no JS at all
So basically use `tabindex`, don't use `<button>` and use the CSS `:focus`

Comment: very nice of u sir but when i click 2nd time on dropdown green div to close the menu. it is not working. thanks but if you can fix that ? and when 2nd time i click on that green div, menu should close ?

Comment: It can be fixed. The menu will close with a second click. Here is an example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8evtxnsL/)